# Presenting a landscape controller over a portrait controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am trying to present a transparent landscape view controller over portrait view controller. In the past if I wanted to show a transparent portrait controller over a portrait controller I would do something like this:

```
- (IBAction) showTransparentController:(id)sender{
    UIViewController* con = <some controller>;
    con.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationOverFullScreen;
    con.view.alpha = 0.7;
    [self presentViewController:con animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

However for landscape over portrait this does not work. Once the the landscape controller is presented the portrait controller is forced to rotate to landscape underneath the landscape controller.

Is there a way to present a transparent landscape view controller over portrait view controller?

Int the gif example below you can see the landscape controller, present over the portrait controller, and then the portrait controller rotates to landscape (notice the black label moves).

[image: Example]

Comment: Did you ever find an answer for this? I know it's been years, but I'm looking for an answer now...

Comment: I ended up just rotating the top view controller manually using a transform

Comment: Thanks for the response!